# Four or More Heads in a Coin Toss

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How would one write a recursion for the number of ways to get 4 or more heads in a row in 10 tosses of a coin?  Would it suffice to use the recursion H(n)=H(n-1)+H(n-2)+H(n-3)+H(n-4) for the number of ways this does not occur?

Is there a better way to count this non-recursively?  For example, is it possible to count directly, conditioning on the number of heads as follows:  $1+2(2^1)+3(2^2)+4(2^3)+5(2^4)+6(2^5)+7(2^6)$, also subtracting off the relevant additional cases.  In general, $(n-(k-1))!(\sum_{i=k}^{n-(k-1)} (2^{n-k}-2^{n-k+1})$ where n is the number of trials, and k is the number of a binary outcome in a row we want (is this right)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "for example", that is a different question from the original one

Comment: @qwr It is, I was just wondering if it is possible to do it non-recursively.

Comment: You don't need recursion, with recursion defined as solving a smaller problem within a bigger problem. Summing each case isn't recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H(n)$ counts the number of ways you don't end up with 4 or more heads out of $n$ flips, you don't need recursion. The probability of not tossing four or more heads is that number divided by total possible flips, $\frac{H(n)}{2^n}$, so the probability of tossing four or more heads is the complement $1 - \frac{H(n)}{2^n}$.

Comment: Sorry H(n) counts the number of ways you don't end up with 4 or more heads out of n flips.